# logging with log4j on wildfly 10.1 using external configuration files

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, wildfly

I'm having problems logging on Wildfly 10.1 using log4j 1.2.15 and external configuration files.

In the EJBs I put the following working code:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BeanClass.class.getName());
PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(configDir + LOG_CONFIG_FILENAME, 30);
```

the code above works logging EJBs.

My question is: why I'm not able to log all the other .java files that aren't EJBs?
In these files there is the following code:

```
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Class_Name.class.getName());
```

and I've also tried to add the configureAndWatch part, but still no logs.

I'm also open to new ideas, so if you can suggest any other working way to log on Wildfly using external configuration files, I will thank you sooo much! :)

Comment: Are you including log4j in your deployment?

Comment: It is included in the Deployment Assembly of each  EAR

Comment: In that case you may want to try excluding the logging subsystem in a [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile)

Comment: Are you actually needing to edit the log4j config in runtime? If not, I would just include your log4j.properties file in the top level of your deployment and wildfly should just pick that up and use for any Logger in that deployment

Comment: Unfortunately I have the requirement of loading the configuration file from the external, I can't put the log4j.properties in my project...